# Android Drop Down list custom layout

Tags: android

I implemented a Drop-Down List for Navigation, but as of right now, the .xml i've been able to supply for style consists only of a TextView and I'm unable to use any kind of Layout, so my question is:

How to implement a Drop-Down navigation like the one on Google Maps App where each row in the Drop Down is Icon + Title + Subtitle(optional).

Comment: Can you Post the code you have tried?